# casperjs evaluate function cannot return data i need

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

cannot get my function to return data correctly
i want to grab the value of this inputbox

```
<input type="text" value="example@outlook.com" maxlength="100" size="40" name="mail"></input>
```

so i built a function like so

```
exports.Details = function() {
casper.thenOpen("https://perfectmoney.is/settings.html", function() { 
var fetch = casper.fetchText('#reg > table:nth-child(3) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1) > table:nth-child(4) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(8) > td:nth-child(2) > input:nth-child(1)')
});
};
```

i am then calling my function like so

```
casper.then(function() {
var item = pief.Details();
console.log(item);
});
```

the result i get is undefiend how can i fix this

Comment: Capture it with xpath, that fetchText statement looks like a nightmare.

Comment: The value ? Try console.log(casper.getElementAttribute("input[type='text'][name='mail']","value"));  or the textContent?

Answer (score 2):

```
casper.then(function(){
     value = this.evaluate(function() {
         return __utils__.findOne('input').getAttribute('value');
     });
});

casper.then(function(){
    this.echo(value);
});
```

I recommend you to add an id for this input. And search by `input#id_name.`